# How to repeat automatically last marginnote on a new page?

Tags: marginpar

I have some margin notes and want the last one to be repeated on a new page. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Like a regular `\marginpar`? Or are you using the [`marginnote` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote)?

Comment: @Werner I am using the regular \marginpar

Comment: @Gernsheim This does not seem to be easy with marginpar. But your question doesn't provide enough information. Please tell us more: Why would you like to repeat a marginpar? Which documentclass do you use? And so on. You may edit your question.

Comment: With no more information, I've closed this as 'too localized'. Request reopening if more information is edited in.