# Publishers and Talmud layout

Tags: lyx-layouts, idxlayout, zwpagelayout

1. a) What **software** do publishers use for creating the complex layout of the Talmud?

Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image]

b) Can anyone recommend to me a software that's easy to use for this?

Comment: Can you please explain what tzuras hadaf or Gemara is? Link? Image, explanaition with your own words ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Tzuras Hadaf means the images (i.e. layout) that are on the pages of the Talmud.

Comment: `flowfram` with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? I'm assuming, though, that this is really done with specialist (or customised) software. It might be worth thinking about what is really essential in the layout and what would be nice but can be given up if necessary.

Comment: Not an immediate solution, but maybe a source of ideas: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24719/5001 (@Raphink's attempt to recreate the first page of a 1564 Geneva Bible...)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141924/7883

Comment: If the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141924/7883 does not satisfy you, perhaps you should offer a bounty there for better answers.  If you’re giving up on `TeX` as software with which to produce this layout, perhaps you should move this question to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or make inquiries at http://typophile.com/.