# Page layout of Mishna Brura text.

Tags: hebrew, grid-typesetting

I'm relatively new with using TeX and primarily use it for writing Mathematics. However a colleague of mine is looking to use TEX for its typesetting properties to actively work with typeset pages.Using the page format commonly seen in the [Mishna Brura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah)

An example page of it looks like this:

[image]

Consisting of a primary text on top with about 5 independent commentaries below.

If anyone knows how to get started with this it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there a specification of the possible layouts? When is a page a proper Mishna Brura page?

Comment: There is no "proper" Mishna Brura page as each page is unique based on how much each commentary takes on the page. But there are five commentaries which approximately fit on the page as the image above.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214684 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141924 will be of interest.

Comment: @Thérèse thank you, but I saw these. But this is a little different where it is more commentary intensive

Comment: Seriously: LaTeX was not designed for pages like this. Try ConTeXt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{wrapfig,blindtext}
\addtolength\textheight{2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}
\blindtext

\footnotesize

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.5\textwidth}
\subsection{note2}
\blindtext
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection{note1}
\blindtext[2]
\subsection{note3}
\Blindlist{enumerate}[2]
\subsection{note4}
Something like this.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MartinSchröder I have no idea what you mean, if you don't have any constructive comments to make best not make any comment at all.

Comment: @MartinSchröder if you happen to have a better suggestion please feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for suggesting wrap fig. It works nicely if we typeset a page at a time, but it does not allow for overflowing to next page of text. Do you see any way to do the? Meaning: In your example, if the text of \subsection{note2} should go over the page, then the layout breaks. Thanks! (Hope it is ok to revive this old thread...)