# How to have text occupy multiple columns in latex?

Tags: multicol, multicolumn, flowfram, newspaper

I am currently using multicols and would like to organize my columns in a way that some paragraphs can occupy multiple columns. Like as follows

[image: columns example]

With the red blue and green lines all being different sections of text. I have already looked at flowfram, but this does not solve my problem because it would only works if each page is painstakingly handcrafted pixel by pixel, em by em, or pt by pt. If there is a tool which simply allows me to define the position of my frames and columns in relation to one another, and define the size of my columns with respect to multicol's \columnsize argument, that tool would suffice.

Comment: You can use [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) for this and specify a layout for a set of pages. Do you have a layout that differs from one page to the next?

Comment: yes. Are there no packages which simply allow me to define the position of the frames with relationship to one another like a table or am I limited to manually building pages by hand?

Comment: In such a case, LaTeX does not seem to be the ideal tool for what you're using it. Instead, you can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) or perhaps [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/indesign.html)...

Comment: One would think that typesetting software as advanced as latex would have such an obvious feature or that someone would have made such a package. Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of latex, is it not a broad typesetting tool but something primarily aimed at stuff that goes straight up and down the page?

Comment: TeX was [designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX#History) so Knuth could be sure *The Art of Computer Programming* would be typeset in the way he wanted. LaTeX, too, is primarily aimed at high-quality output for scholarly works, not any kind of document conceivable. While it may well be possible to do what you want, most people use it to write pretty traditional types of works.

Comment: LaTeX is powerful, but it's not a broad typesetting tool. Just like a butter knife can spread all kinds of delicious toppings, it's probably not the best tool for cutting a tree. Sure it can, but it'll take quite a while, require you to where extra gloves to avoid blisters and probably have many moments where you just want to give up. :-| You can achieve the layout you mention using [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram), but it may just be difficult to maintain. TeX enjoys a recti-linear setup, but has arbitrary paragraph forming difficulty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129137/5764).

Comment: Possibly LaTeX 3 will provide something closer to what you're looking for. There's some code for this already, but highly experimental. You certainly can do this kind of thing in LaTeX, but it is really designed to ensure consistent layout throughout. If you want an inconsistent layout, you are fighting it all the way.

Comment: @Werner Do you really think it could? If it were a very small tree, maybe, but otherwise ...?

Comment: You can test if [`PaperTeX`](http://ctan.org/pkg/papertex) is enough flexible for your needs. Or you can also try combining `magazine` and `raster` libraries from  [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Comment: You can also do page layout using tikzpagenodes.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud/215188?s=1|1.3476#215188

Answer (score 3):

I dot not understand your problem by `flowfram`, as you can make layouts for several pages, but may be you find useful my question  [Three-columns text with figures of 2\columnwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70175/three-columns-text-with-figures-of-2-columnwidth).

However, without this package, you can use minipages, or minipages  and multicolumns:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article} 
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document} 
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{.32\linewidth}
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \lipsum[4]
 \end{minipage}}\hfill%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[c]{.65\linewidth}
\hfil \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\par\bigskip
 \lipsum[5] 
\begin{multicols}{2}
 \lipsum[6-7]   
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

See also the [textpos](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package.