# How to insert two images (not really) side by side but at overlapping height

Tags: beamer, graphics, wrapfigure, sidebyside

I am preparing my lecture notes in beamer slides. In a particular frame, a `block` (custom defined) consists of two `tikzpicture`s and some texts. The only way to arrange them is like the following image.

[image]

I have no idea how to achieve this. Please help. The particular `block` is not a `listed` environment, so `wrapfigure` works. Following is an `MWE` to save you from writing the first few lines of code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}
            content
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**PS:** Please feel free to change the title of this question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud

Comment: @JohnKormylo the Talmud example is a lot harder though.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\parshape 11
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-8cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-8cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-8cm\relax
4cm \dimexpr \textwidth-8cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr \textwidth-4cm\relax
0cm \textwidth
\noindent
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-4cm,-6\baselineskip){\includegraphics[width=3.8cm]{example-image-a}}
\put(\dimexpr\textwidth-7.8cm\relax,-9\baselineskip){\includegraphics[width=3.8cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{picture}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

the `\parshape` primitive takes a sequence of lengths being the indent and length of each line, with a number being the length of the sequence of pairs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I am getting a hard time adjusting the rigid units in your code into my `block`. Right now, I am trying to create an MWE.