Multiple columns with different widths - complex layout
I am having troubles typesetting more complex layout that consists of multiple columns with different widths and vertically rotated text.
Layout image

I've trield multiple packages such as \multicol \minipage \tabular but none of them seemed fit for the solution.
The question
Is this type of layout actually doable in LaTex? If yes approach should I use?

You can do this with minipages, \parboxes, tabular and several other basic LaTeX concepts in addition with \rotatebox from package graphicx. You can also use pgf or tabularray. And there are also packages to generate QR-codes. And please note: This is not a do-it-for-me site. So you should show at least, what you've tried and explain the problem with this try. But you should also always focus on a single problem, (e.g. how to rotate text).

@cabohah Thanks for help. Im just generaly asking if latex can do this. I know how to generate the qr code or rotate the texts. Im just having trouble with fitting it all together with the layout as the whole.

The flowfram package can handle almost page layout (see, but you have to perform the layout in the preamble.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud  The rotated text will have to be done inside the frame.

latex can dothat easily enough, just use \parbox of different widths, the one thing it ca't do is have automatic page breaking from one column or page to another of a different width as all line breaking happens before the column is broken in to pages/columns so you can't re-justify the text for the new column width. But with positioned text as here or with manua; page breaks there is no problem.

Yes, it can be done. With enough effort, virtually any output can be created in LaTeX. I am no tabular expert, but I've included an attempt below, as an example. As already noted, this is a broad question, and a MWE would be very helpful to demonstrate precisely what you wish to achieve and under what specifications.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % prevent overfull hbox from wide table
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox
\usepackage{colortbl} % for \cellcolor

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}p{3cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}|}
\hline\multicolumn{9}{|l|}{}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\LARGE Longer longer heading line 1} & & \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}{} & & \multicolumn{4}{r|}{123-456-7}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\LARGE Longer longer heading line 2} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}{QR}} & & & & &\\[0.5cm]
28.2.2024 & Some venue & & & & & & &\\
20:00 & 100 USD & & & & & & &\\[1cm]
\multicolumn{5}{|l}{Basic ticket} & & & &\\[0.5cm]
\multicolumn{5}{|l}{Seat 24} & & & &\\
\multicolumn{5}{|l}{\tiny very tiny longer sentence. very tiny longer sentence.} & \rotatebox{90}{28.2.2024} & \rotatebox{90}{20:00} & \rotatebox{90}{Basic ticket} & \rotatebox{90}{Seat 24}\\[0.5cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



I would apply tikz for this. It's possible to complete it using only minipages or \parboxes but tikz adds a little more control over positioning and alignment.
If you want to adjust spacing between lines of text, use setspace. Then, either add one of the optional settings: [doublespacing], [onehaldspacing], insert a switch-macro, s.a. \onehalfspacing or \doublespacing. If you need fine tuning, use \setstretch{<factor>} with 1.0 being the standard spacing. Or simply append \vspace{} for one-time extra vertical spacing.
I don't know if there are any dimensions of that ticket. Therefore, the example below use some arbitrary values for widths and he height
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength\ticketheight
\setlength\ticketheight{6cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 1cm,
        every node/.style = {
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer sep=0pt,
        },
    ]
    \node (A) {%
        \parbox[t][\ticketheight][s]{7cm}{
            {\LARGE\setstretch{1}%
                Longer longer heading line 1
         
                Longer longer heading line 2
            \par}

            \vspace{\fill}%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm} l@{}}
                28.2.2024 & Some venue \\
                20:00     & 100 USD
            \end{tabular}
         
            \vspace{\fill}%
            Basic ticket
         
            Seat 24
         
            \vspace{\fill}%
            {\tiny\setstretch{1}%
               Much much longer sentence. Much much longer sentence.
               
               Description at the bottom.
            \par}}
    };
    \node [right=of A] (B) {
        \parbox[t][\ticketheight]{3cm}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    };
    \node [right=of B] (C) {
        \parbox[t][\ticketheight][s]{2cm}{
            {\centering
                123-456-7
            \par}

            \vspace{\fill}%
            \raggedleft\onehalfspacing\small
            \rotatebox{90}{%
                \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
                    28.2.2024 \\
                    20:00 \\
                    Basic ticket \\
                    Seat 24
                \end{tabular}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


