# Page break between text and table

Tags: page-breaking

I am having a problem with a page break that occurs in one of my document wich appears like this :
[image: Document]
I would like some of my text to be located between the pagebreak and my table. I have struggled with some `\nopagebreak` commands but without any success so far :

```
\footnote{\cf{} Annexe \ref{bilan_prev} : \nameref{bilan_prev} page \pageref{bilan_prev}}. Avec un résultat quasi nul, les sommes dues au titre de l'\ac{is} seraient ainsi dérisoires.\nopagebreak[0]

En outre, si des activités lucratives mineures devaient advenir afin d'aider à équilibrer le budget, en s'assurant que la gestion de l'association soit effectivement désintéressée, que les activités lucratives restent significativement minoritaires et que les montants de celles-ci ne dépassent pas la limite de \num{60540}\,\euro{} hors taxe, l'\aero{} n'aurait aucun mal à faire jouer la franchise des activités lucratives accessoires.\\\nopagebreak[0]

Par ailleurs, la \ac{cet} s'avère également négligeable. En effet, la seule possession en matière d'immeubles bâtis est une construction sur sol d'autrui évaluée à \num{37419}\,\euro{}. En l'absence de réponse du Service des Impôts des Entreprises suite à ma demande concernant la valeur locative d'un tel bien, on supposera que celle-ci, qui constitue la base de calcul de la première composante de la \ac{cet}, la \ac{cfe}, est suffisamment faible par rapport aux éléments qui suivent pour la considérer  comme négligeable.\nopagebreak[0]

De plus, la valeur ajoutée qui constitue l'assiette de la deuxième composante de la \ac{cet}, la \ac{cvae}, est également relativement faible. Déterminée à partir du chiffre d'affaires, majoré d'autres produits et diminué de certaines charges, son calcul à partir du bilan de 2014 donne :\nopagebreak[4]

\begin{center}
\noindent
\resizebox{0.75\textwidth}{!}{
\tikz\node[draw,rounded corners=0.75cm]{
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Ventes de marchandises&932\\
Production vendue de biens et services&490 632\\
Transferts de charges (refacturation de frais)&\multicolumn{1}{r}{6 088}\\\cline{2-2}
Chiffre d'affaires&497 652\\
Autres produits&10\\
Subventions&23 982\\
Transferts de charges déductibles de la valeur ajoutée&21 786\\
\\
Achats de matières premières&-1 330\\
Autres achats et charges externes&\multicolumn{1}{r}{-422 177}\\\cline{2-2}
Valeur Ajoutée&119 923
\end{tabular}
};}
\end{center}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: normally you would put the table in a floating `table` environment to allow latex to move it to improve the page break.

Comment: but I really need it to be juste after the "son calcul à partir du bilan de 2014 donne :"...

Comment: just put `\pagebreak` a few lines up, wherever you want the page to be left short.

Comment: Since it obviously isn't going to fit where you want it, you either need to shrink it or reorganize.  If you intend to shrink, there are ways to determine exactly how much room is left of the page.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228978/figure-content-does-not-appear-on-even-pages-after-introducing-changes-to-the-ou/229099?s=1|0.1171#229099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like this, which are inherently related to visual formatting, are best solved by applying suitable page formatting commands, given explicitly during final revision, as D.C. suggests.  However, it’s very easy to define a variant of the `center` environment which will never start a new page above itself:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment*{nobreakcenter}{%
  \trivlist
  \@beginparpenalty \@M
  % Uncomment the following line to prohibit page breaks below the environment 
  % as well:
  % \@endparpenalty \@M
  \centering
  \item\relax
}{\endtrivlist}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

Just a few more lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a
few more lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a few more
lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a few more lines.  Just a few more lines.
Just a few more lines.

\begin{nobreakcenter}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{nobreakcenter}

\lipsum[7-8]

\end{document}
```

Of course, the *contents* of the environment can still be split accross pages; if desired, this can be avoided too.