# `altacv' class: How to use \marginpar{...} when no need to align the top of the contents to any \cvsection title in the "main" bar

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, cv, marginpar, altacv

### Background

altacv is a class for preparing CVs. Following template is used for cv preparation. template link: https://www.overleaf.com/articles/anurags-resume/jdfqhmhqzbxv

It has two-column structure as shown below: [image: Format of the output]

### Problem

I am preparing a 2-page resume. On the second page, I am inserting the right bar using the following command:

```
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Experience 2}
```

The top of the right column is aligned with `\cvsection` header (`Experience 2`) in the main/left column. I do not need it to be aligned with the header in the main column, rather I want it to be aligned with the top or start from the top of the second page.

In order to achieve this, as shown below, the template suggests that `\marginpar{...}` should be used.

> %% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an
> optional parameter to \cvsection. You can always just use
> \marginpar{...} if you do not need to align the top of the contents
> to any \cvsection title in the "main" bar.

However, it is not clear to me, how to use it.

### Tested routes

I have tested the following ways of using `\marginpar{...}` to allow the right bar text to be aligned with the top:

```
 1. \cvsection[page2sidebar]{Professional experience}
        \marginpar{...}

    
 2. \marginpar{...}
    \cvsection[page2sidebar]{Professional experience}
    
 3. \cvsection[\marginpar{page2sidebar}]{Professional experience}
```

None of the three ways resulted in a desired outcome. How to align the second page sidebar with the top of the page instead of the section from where it is invoked?

Comment: In the main (left) content, are you inserting a page break manually? If so, it is a simpler problem to solve.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I am not manually inserting the page breaks.

Comment: Darn. In that case [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69517) question may be useful to you...